# Compute the number of 7-digit sequences that contain a 5-digit consecutive substring

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Let say any 7-digit sequence, even 0000000 is a valid number. Compute the number of sequences that contain a 5-digit consecutive substring. For example “23456” and “12345”?

Approached it as (where X can be (0-9)) :
Which gives me a total as 1800, however the answer is 1700. Can you please point out what I over-counted and share a wise way to approach similar question ?

```
 0 1 2 3 4 X X 
 1 2 3 4 5 X X
 2 3 4 5 6 X X
 3 4 5 6 7 X X
 4 5 6 7 8 X X
 5 6 7 8 9 X X 

 X 0 1 2 3 4 X  
 X 1 2 3 4 5 X 
 X 2 3 4 5 6 X 
 X 3 4 5 6 7 X 
 X 4 5 6 7 8 X 
 X 5 6 7 8 9 X

 X X 0 1 2 3 4  
 X X 1 2 3 4 5 
 X X 2 3 4 5 6 
 X X 3 4 5 6 7 
 X X 4 5 6 7 8 
 X X 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: What have you overcounted?  How about the string `0 1 2 3 4 5 6`?  You counted it once when you noticed it had `0 1 2 3 4` in it, you counted it again when you noticed it had `1 2 3 4 5` in it, and again when you noticed it had `2 3 4 5 6` in it.  Similarly so for any other string with more than 5 consecutive digits in a row.

Comment: This problem is a good setting to apply the Inclusion-Exclusion principle.

Comment: The standard way to correct the overcounting is called the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion–exclusion_principle).

Comment: Can you please @Carl  or Arthur show me how you would use inclusion exclusion principle ?

Comment: the question should be more defined(wording is not precise) as `Compute the number of sequence that contain only a 5-digit consecutive substring` or `Compute the number of sequence that contain at least a 5-digit consecutive substring.` here first one would restrict a 6 or 7 digit substring while the second question would allow those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are overcounting the number of such strings: for example  $0 1 2 3 4 5 6$ is counted three times:
as a member of $0 1 2 3 4 X X$, of  $X 1 2 3 4 5 X$, and of $X X 2 3 4 5 6$.

As explained by the comments the right tool to use is 
the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Hint. Let $S(01234)$ be the set of 7-digit sequences which contain a copy of the string $01234$ then, from your scheme,
$$|S(01234)|=3\cdot 10\cdot 10=300.$$

By the inclusion-exclusion principle, the number of 7-digit sequences such that contain **at least** a 5-digit consecutive substring in **increasing order** is
$$\begin{align}&|S(01234)|+|S(12345)|+\dots+|S(56789)|\\&-
|S(012345)|-|S(123456)|-\dots-|S(456789)|\end{align}.$$
P.S. In order to apply the inclusion-exclusion principle you should consider the intersections of the sets $S(\cdot)$. Note that 
$$S(01234)\cap S(12345)=S(012345),\\
S(01234)\cap S(23456)=S(0123456),\\
S(01234)\cap S(34567)=\emptyset,\\
S(01234)\cap S(12345)\cap S(23456)=S(0123456)
.$$

Comment: @StackExangeLearner Is it clear now how to use PIE?

Answer (score 0):

You are counting some strings twice.

For example, $$xx56789$$ and $$x45678x$$ both results in $$3456789$$